# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at 0x0 when calling dll compiled with Julia PackageCompiler

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, packagecompiler.jl

I am compiling Julia program as dll and trying to call from another program.

The Julia program is as follows (I am planning to use commented out pkg):

```
module pjname
# using Statistics
# using CSV
# using DataFrames
# using DSP
# # using Plots
# using Dates
# using FindPeaks1D
Base.@ccallable function function_name(slen::Cint)::Cint
    println(1)
    return 0
end
end # module
```

The program I am using to compile the code is:

```
using PackageCompiler
PackageCompiler.create_sysimage(; sysimage_path="./src/prog_dl.dll", script="./src/prog.jl")
```

and the program I call the dll is as follows:

```
using Libdl
libmg = dlopen("H:/julia/pjname3/src/prog_dl.dll")
function_name = dlsym(libmg, :func_name)
ccall(function_name, Cint, (Cint,), Int32(1))
```

I get the following error. Could someone help me to figure out this issue? I tried Julia version 1.6.5 and 1.7.0 but both of them didn't work. I am using windows and VS Code as IDE.

> Please submit a bug report with steps to reproduce this fault, and any
> error messages that follow (in their entirety). Thanks. Exception:
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at 0x0 -- unknown function (ip:
> 0000000000000000) in expression starting at none:1        unknown
> function (ip: 0000000000000000) function_name at
> H:\julia\pjname3\src\prog_dl.dll (unknown line) top-level scope at
> .\none:1 jl_toplevel_eval_flex at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:871
> jl_toplevel_eval at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:886
> [inlined] jl_toplevel_eval_in at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:929
> eval at .\boot.jl:360 [inlined] evaluate_foreigncall at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\JuliaInterpreter\src\interpret.jl:166
> eval_rhs at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\JuliaInterpreter\src\interpret.jl:402
> step_expr! at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\JuliaInterpreter\src\interpret.jl:556
> step_expr! at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\JuliaInterpreter\src\interpret.jl:611
> finish! at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\JuliaInterpreter\src\commands.jl:14
> finish_and_return! at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\JuliaInterpreter\src\commands.jl:30
> unknown function (ip: 0000000060da89d5) finish_stack! at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\JuliaInterpreter\src\commands.jl:60
> unknown function (ip: 0000000060da8925)
> #debug_command#83 at c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\JuliaInterpreter\src\commands.jl:474
> debug_command at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\JuliaInterpreter\src\commands.jl:416
> unknown function (ip: 0000000060dc8a09) jl_apply at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703
> [inlined] jl_f__call_latest at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:714
> #invokelatest#2 at .\essentials.jl:708 [inlined] invokelatest at .\essentials.jl:706 [inlined] our_debug_command at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\DebugAdapter\src\debugger_core.jl:67
> startdebug at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\DebugAdapter\src\packagedef.jl:106
> startdebugger at
> c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\packages\VSCodeDebugger\src\VSCodeDebugger.jl:39
> unknown function (ip: 0000000060d6bca3) jl_apply at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703
> [inlined] do_call at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:115
> eval_value at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:204
> eval_stmt_value at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:155
> [inlined] eval_body at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:576
> jl_interpret_toplevel_thunk at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:670
> jl_toplevel_eval_flex at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:877
> jl_toplevel_eval_flex at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:825
> jl_toplevel_eval at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:886
> [inlined] jl_toplevel_eval_in at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:929
> eval at .\boot.jl:360 [inlined] include_string at .\loading.jl:1116
> _include at .\loading.jl:1170       include at .\Base.jl:384 exec_options at .\client.jl:285
> _start at .\client.jl:485 jfptr__start_46900.clone_1 at C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.6.5\lib\julia\sys.dll
> (unknown line) jl_apply at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703
> [inlined] true_main at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\jlapi.c:560
> repl_entrypoint at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\jlapi.c:702
> mainCRTStartup at
> /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/cli\loader_exe.c:51
> BaseThreadInitThunk at C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (unknown line)
> RtlUserThreadStart at C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (unknown line)
> Allocations: 14028713 (Pool: 14021110; Big: 7603); GC: 16 The terminal
> process
> "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.6.5\bin\julia.exe
> '--color=yes', '--startup-file=no', '--history-file=no',
> '--project=h:\julia\pjname3',
> 'c:\Users\user_name.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.5.8\scripts\debugger\run_debugger.jl',
> '\.\pipe\vsc-jl-dbg-7bbf4da0-9e5b-4d64-8fbb-db76fd01a2af',
> '\.\pipe\vsc-jl-cr-e192e8b6-1dd8-46c2-90a6-1074d122bd3c'" terminated
> with exit code: 1.

Comment: `dlsym` returned NULL as it couldn't find the desired symbol. After `dlopen` and `dlsym`, check if the returned value is NULL.

Comment: Path given to dlopen is the dll generated using PackageCompiler. Does libmg = dlopen("./src/prog_dl.dll") works? I am actually not sure if I should pass the dll as absolute path or not.

Comment: You cannot have your code in global scope like that. Pointers are deserialized to NULL. You need to recreate the pointer when Julia starts. For example by running the `dlopen` and `dlsym` in the `__init__` function of the module.

Comment: Thank you Kristoffer, but I think I don't understand your comment. Could you give me a sample code or reference website so that I can understand it?